# How to use postcss-import with tailwindcss-rails and importmaps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, import-maps, postcss-import

I started a new rails project and am attempting to get tailwind running on it.

I'd like to be able to have the tailwind css files separated for organizational reasons.

Relevant gems in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "sprockets-rails"
gem "importmap-rails"
gem "tailwindcss-rails"
```

I ran `bin/importmap pin postcss-import` which added a bunch of pins to my `config/importmap.rb` file.

I would have assumed this would allow those node modules to be accessed from JS files from within the application? So then in `config/tailwind.config.js` I have this:

```
module.exports = {
  // which files tailwind can access https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}',
    './app/views/**/*'
  ],
  plugins: [
    require("postcss-import"),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

For my CSS, I have `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css` that looks like this:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import "tailwind/font"
```

And I also have `app/assets/stylesheets/tailwind/font.css` that looks like this:

```
@layer base {
  h1 {
    @apply 2xl;
  }
  h2 {
    @apply h2;
  }
}
```

However, when I go to build the CSS (via `bin/dev`), I get this error:

```
18:00:48 css.1  | Rebuilding...
18:00:48 css.1  | Error: Cannot find module 'postcss-import'
18:00:48 css.1  | Require stack:
18:00:48 css.1  | - /home/zifnab/projects/my_project/config/tailwind.config.js
18:00:48 css.1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at Function._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1955:46)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at _resolve (/snapshot/tailwindcss/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:250334)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at jiti (/snapshot/tailwindcss/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:252917)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at /home/zifnab/projects/my_project/config/tailwind.config.js:112:5
18:00:48 css.1  |     at evalModule (/snapshot/tailwindcss/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:255614)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at jiti (/snapshot/tailwindcss/node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:253542)
18:00:48 css.1  |     at /snapshot/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:37:30
18:00:48 css.1  |     at loadConfig (/snapshot/tailwindcss/lib/lib/load-config.js:39:6) {
18:00:48 css.1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
18:00:48 css.1  |   requireStack: [
18:00:48 css.1  |     '/home/zifnab/projects/my_project/config/tailwind.config.js'
18:00:48 css.1  |   ]
18:00:48 css.1  | }
```

Which indicates to me that the importmaps aren't currently working during this build step to include the `postcss-import` module... I would rather not fall back on doing yarn packages, I'd like to stick with the rails 7 way of importmaps if possible... what can I do here to make it recognize the module from importmaps while building this CSS...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `tailwindcss-rails` gem which uses [standalone](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/standalone-cli) tailwind executable. Postcss is already part of the [build](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/8580), you can remove this:

```js
require("postcss-import")
```

Your imports have to come before anything else:

```scss
// postcss requires imports to be first
@import "./tailwind/font";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

If this is not ideal you can switch everything to `@import`:

```scss
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";

@import "./tailwind/font";
```

Comment: Ok well now I feel dumb! I tried what you mentioned (putting it as the first directive), but `@import "tailwind/font"` wasn't working so I assumed postcss-import must not be available by default... I just needed to prefix it with `"./"` and now it does work XD Thank you so much for saving me more headaches.